# Bind UltraCombo to distinct values in an UltraGrid column

Tags: .net, infragistics

I have an Infragistics UltraGrid. In this `myUltraGrid` I have a column "CITIES".

I have a UltraCombo under that grid: `myUltraCombo`.

Can I bind `myUltraCombo` in order to contain the list of (distinct) cities + a `*` value (all cities) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the UltraCombo as the editor for the CITIES column.  If all of the rows will have the same values you could filter the list before binding the UltraCombo so that it is only bound to the cities that you want to be available.  If you are looking to provide filtering of the list on individual rows then you could use the following blog post as a reference:
http://blogs.infragistics.com/winforms/codesamples/creating-a-dropdown-list-in-a-grid-cell-whose-list-values-are-dependent-on-another-cell.aspx

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Here I use Method syntax linq query on the ultragrid

```
myUltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Rows.All.ToList.Select(Function(r) CType(r, UltraGridRow).Cells("CITIES").Value).Distinct.ToList
```

I would use this method only if you don't have access to these values via another data source.